# Dialog Box Closes Immediately After It Opens

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

I have a dialog box that I am using for user input, and it was working just fine, now no matter what I do the dialog pops up for one second and then the program dies with no warning, calling `WM_DESTROY` even after I comment out all the possible exits. There is only one error, which is the `no_init_all` error, but that shows up every time there is a runtime error, and is pretty useless in trying to find the solution.

Here is my code:

project.cpp

```
BOOL CreateMyDialog(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    HWND hWnd = CreateDialog(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(myDialogResource), NULL, (DLGPROC)myDialogProcess);
    if (!hWnd) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    myDialogGlobalHandle = hWnd;
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    //UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK myDialogProcess(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrlEx;

    InitCtrlEx.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    InitCtrlEx.dwICC = ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrlEx);

    switch(msg) {
        case WM_INITDIALOG: {
            //Do stuff to prep the dialog
            return TRUE;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);
            break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

project.rc

```
myDialogResource DIALOGEX 600, 400, 286, 108
    STYLE DS_SYSMODAL | DS_SETFONT | DS_SETFOREGROUND | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION
    EXSTYLE WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW /*| WS_EX_APPWINDOW*/
    CAPTION "My Dialog"
    FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
    BEGIN
        COMBOBOX        dropdownList,112,7,61,30,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
        //... it's all syntactically correct controls that still work the split second the dialog is on the screen
    END
```

This is the shortened code, and even with this the dialog opens on top of itself and glitches on the screen. With my full code, it appears normally for a split-second before the app closes. I believe if I can fix this small bit, I can find the issue with my dialog. So my question is, what's the issue?

**EDIT:**

Here is my `wWinMain`:

```cpp
HWND myDialogGlobalHandle;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrlEx;

    InitCtrlEx.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    InitCtrlEx.dwICC = ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrlEx);
    if (!CreateMyDialog(hInstance)) {
        //return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        MSG message = { 0 };
        while (GetMessage(&message, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
            if (!IsDialogMessage(myDialogGlobalHandle, &message)) {
                DispatchMessage(&message);
            }
        }
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_PROJECT));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Create yourself an answer instead or accept one of the existing answers.

Comment: Why do you have 2 message loops? And why are you re-initializing the ComCtrl library on every message received by the dialog? That init does not belong in `myDialogProcess()` at all.

Comment: Glad you found the solution yourself. Could you post an answer to end this thread.It will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, all my code was correct. The issue was with the `case` statements in my dialog procedure, for some reason Visual Studio didn't like brackets in the `case` statements. After trying everything and then just replacing them with `break;` statements, my code started working again.